# How to use string in Ruby variable name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, variables, dynamic-variables

I have a string that I want to use as part of a variable name. Specifically, in Rails route paths:

```
<%= foo_path %>
<%= bar_path %>
```

I want the first part of the route name to be dynamic. So something like

```
@lol = "foo"
<%= [@lol]_path %> # <-- This would really be the "foo_path" variable
```

Can Ruby do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sure:

```
lol = 'foo'

send "#{lol}_path"
# or
send lol + '_path'
```

Explanation: [`Object#send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-send) sends the method to (i.e. "calls" the method on) the receiver. As with any method call, without an explicit receiver (e.g. `some_object.send 'foo'`) the current context becomes the receiver, so calling `send :foo` is equivalent to `self.send :foo`. In fact Rails uses this technique behind the scenes quite a lot ([e.g.](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/a9f3c9da01d721963d05949604ead909aaabbf36/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/builder/has_many.rb#L24)).

Comment: epic!! for purpose of pedagogy, how would someone learn something like this? Just from longer exposure to Ruby?

Comment: Exposure will help, certainly, but if you're going to use Ruby you could do much worse than to read through the docs for as many of the core classes as you can, in particular [Object](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html) and [Kernel](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html) (but really [none of them](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/) is very long). And don't forget [the Pickaxe](http://www.rubycentral.com/pickaxe/), the seminal (and free) Ruby book.

Comment: I read those source, and I don't get them. It helps so much more when someone explains, teaches, or shows me. Or at least gets me to the point of being able to understand. There are technical glass ceilings when starting out that become invisible to seasoned programmers.

Comment: The Pickaxe link in my previous comment is broken. Here's a working link: http://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/

Answer (score 2):

Something more!

```
class Person
  attr_accessor :pet
end

class Pet
  def make_noise
     "Woof! Woof!"
  end
end

var_name = "pet"
p = Person.new
p.pet = Pet.new
(p.send "#{var_name}").make_noise
```

So what's happening here is:
`p.send "some_method"` calls `p.some_method` and the parenthesis surrounding makes the chaining possible i.e. call `p.pet.make_noise` in the end. Hope I'm clear.

Comment: I think it would be more idiomatic to write `p.send(var_name).make_noise`.